# Add Missing Android Platform

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, nativescript, node-modules

There is functionality in Android API level 30 that I need to use in my Angular project.

I'm sure this is as simple as a NPM command for tns-platform-declarations but I just can't seem to come up with it.  I've been able to add the missing files manually but when I do the project keeps referencing level 17.  The build process wipes out and reloads node_modules anyway.

[image: Current API levels]

```json
"tns-platform-declarations": {
  "version": "6.5.15",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tns-platform-declarations/-/tns-platform-declarations-6.5.15.tgz",
  "integrity": "",
  "dev": true
},
"@nativescript/android": {
  "version": "8.4.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@nativescript/android/-/android-8.4.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "",
  "dev": true
},
"tns-android": {
  "version": "6.5.3",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tns-android/-/tns-android-6.5.3.tgz",
  "integrity": "",
  "dev": true
},
```